# Getting Signal strength of the Wifi connected(not getting called)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wireless, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to get the Wi-Fi signal strength of the AP connected. When I try to run the below code, nothing is returned/displays error.

```
public class Wifi extends uiscenario {
    public void onReceive(WifiManager wifiManager) throws UiObjectNotFoundException, InterruptedException, RemoteException, IOException {
        System.out.println("level");
        int numberOfLevels=4;
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
        System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
    }
}
```

How to get the signal strength of the wifi connected and also how to get the scan results of wifi and connect to the wifi which has strongest signal strength?

Updated code

```
public class Wifi extends UiScenario { 
       private static WifiManager wifiManager;
           public void wifiscan() throws UiObjectNotFoundException,InterruptedException,RemoteException, IOException { 
           int numberOfLevels=5; 
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
           int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);        
           System.out.println("Bars =" +level);
     }
}
```

Getting error in this line(WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it should work. Its working fine for me.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                            int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();

                            System.out.println("Link Speed is======"+linkSpeed);
```

Comment: I believe am not initializing wifi manager here..can you give th e full code?

Comment: just import lib from control+shift+O and if u still getting error then paste your code

Comment: When i try to run the above piece of code, Nullpointer exception throws.Am i missing something here?

Comment: no dude it work fine at my side ohk where u got this error means in which line u getting this error

Comment: In this line, error displays: WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

Comment: i didn't assist to to add this line dude just see sharply to my code

Comment: public class TestWifi extends UiScenario { 
 private static Context context;
 public void ttwifi() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, InterruptedException, RemoteException, IOException {
     WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
     int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
      System.out.println("Link Speed is======" +linkSpeed);                                                                                        Now getting error(nullpointerexception) @ line 16 ["System.out.println("Link Speed is======" +linkSpeed)"]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47371/discussion-between-user3135727-and-bhanu-sharma)

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest uses permissions for wifi and read phone state your code is perfect,
it should work else try this.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
```

Comment: I'm running on unrooted device..Also,  this code is not going into this method itself

Comment: In logcat, it displays failed to issue private commands in wpasupplicant.am i missing something here?